# Create custom count measure

Tags: ssas, mdx

I using an incident management cube to try to determine how many tickets were opened by a specific set of users. For instance, if there were 80,000 tickets opened - how many were opened by `.[Submitter].&[xAutoData]` and `.[Submitter].&[xAutoVoice]`?

Sounds pretty easy but I'm just learning MDX so this is a bit of an uphill battle. I'm thinking the best way is to use a custom measure but the closest I've got to any kind of result was by using this query.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[AutoTickets] AS
COUNT({[INC - Incident Management].[Submitter].&[xAutoData],[INC - Incident Management].[Submitter].&[xAutoVoice]})

SELECT
{[Total Incidents],[AutoTickets]} ON 0,
{[INC - Incident Management].[Assigned Group]} ON 1
FROM [Incident Management Cube];
```

[image]

All it ever does is return '2' when there should be quite a bit more.

A point in the right direction would be appreciated and I think would help me learn what's going on behind the scenes.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Over the past few days, I've got a bit closer. I think I need to use a `SUM` function combined with an `IIF`.

Something like

```
WITH Member [Measures].[AutoTickets] AS
SUM(IIF([INC - Incident Management].[Submitter] = [INC - Incident Management].[Submitter].&[na\xData] OR
    [INC - Incident Management].[Submitter] = [INC - Incident Management].[Submitter].&[na\xVoice],1,0))
```

But this returns an error. If I test the query without the SUM, the IIF part does work as expected so I think I'm missing one more piece on how I'm supposed to use the SUM function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify your question a little bit more in terms of what you want to achieve. From the query that you have provided, the calculated member "AutoTickets" counts only the set members of the [Submitter] attribute of [INC - Incident Management] dimension that you have provided with exact tuples and that number will always be 2 {xAutoData and xAutoVoice} across all dimensions, it's like a constant.

Suppose that you want to know how many [Submitter]'s contributed to the Total Incident measure, than I suggest that you try the following statement:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[AutoTickets] AS
COUNT(NonEmpty({[INC - Incident Management].[Submitter].Members),([Measures].[Total 
Incidents])})

SELECT
{[Total Incidents],[AutoTickets]} ON 0,
{[INC - Incident Management].[Assigned Group]} ON 1
FROM [Incident Management Cube];
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have a measure "[Measures].[TicketCount]" which gives the count of tickets, the below query would give you tickets for 
"[Submitter].&[xAutoData] and .[Submitter].&[xAutoVoice]". You just replace with the relevant measure.

```
select [Measures].[TicketCount] on columns,
{[INC - Incident Management].[Submitter].&[xAutoData],[INC - Incident Management].[Submitter].&[xAutoVoice]}
on rows 
from [Incident Management Cube]
```

Comment: @Brian Mitchell did the query help?